# wxWidgets Libraries missing from 3.1.0

Tags: wxwidgets

I am building a solution with CMake that uses wxWidgets. I have downloaded the source code for 3.1.0 and compiled it without issue. However, there are three libraries that my solution needs that are not in 3.1.0: dbgrid, mono, and odbc. I tried compiling 3.0.2, but VStudio 2015 will not compile the source code because it is outdated. I tried building 3.0.2 with GCC, but the Makefile was not recognized.

Any thoughts/suggestions on how I can build or find these three libraries, or build wxWidgets 3.0.2?

Thank you.

Comment: By "mono" do you mean the [Monolithic](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxWidgets_Build_Configurations) build? (all libraries in one file)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the components with the same version known to work with your "solution". For example, use the same `wxWidgets` version that worked without issues.

On a more detailed note, `ODBC` component, including `dbgrid`, have been removed from anything later than `wxWidgets` `2.8`; I have no idea what "mono" is but it doesn't sound like anything in `wxWidgets`. So going with any `3.x` version is not going to help you. You might need to dig up version `2.8.12` from somewhere.

Also, for the sake of completeness, I have no idea what "the Makefile was not recognized" means, but `GCC` is a pretty reliable way of building `wxWidgets`, regardless the version of either of the two or the flavour of the former.